# C++ implicit datatype conversion from unsigned to signed

Tags: c++, types

I know that lower data types are cast into higher data types (e.g. int -> unsigned int -> float -> etc.) but I'm unsure of the following:

```
int var = 5u - 10; // var = -5
auto var = 5u - 10; // var = 4294967291
```

5u is unsigned but in the first case why -10 (signed integer) isn't converted to unsigned value while in the second case it does? In the first case the signed value isn't converted to an unsigned one and this is odd to me

Comment: `5u - 10` evaluates to an `unsigned int` according to C Standard.

Comment: The result of the subtraction is `unsigned` in both cases, but in the first case the result is converted to the destination type. Hence `4294967291` gets converted to `-5`

Comment: Seeing as the code [with the printouts given] won't work in C, I expect that this is C++.

Comment: @Praetorian you're correct, put it as an aswer and I'll mark as accepted

Comment: Um I think you invented this alleged heirarchy of type conversions

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My respect to you is mutual.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't devise anything. I'm just studying: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-type-conversion-and-casting/

Comment: @JohnnyPauling: Why not prefer [a nice, peer-reviewed C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), instead of a random tutorial on the internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "signed integer literal": `5u - 10` is actually the subtraction of 10 from 5u.

The result (of the subtraction) is unsigned, and goes to overflow, giving as a result "5 numbers less than the overflown 0" (4294967291 = 2<sup>32</sup>-5)

The first statement initialize an `int`, hence the unsigned compile time constant is reinterpreted as int. The result is correct (-5) because your hardware use 2s-complement arithmetic. (-5 and 4294967291 are the same 32 bit pattern)

The second statement initialize a variable whose type is inferred by the literal. And it is `unsigned`.

Answer (score 3):

Right-hand sides of *both* of your examples work entirely in the domain of *unsigned* type. I.e. both of your expressions `5u - 10` behave identically, which is not surprising, since they are the same. There's no conversion to `int` (as you seem to incorrectly assume) within the `5u - 10` expression in either case.

Expression `5u - 10` is always evaluated in the domain of unsigned type and produce unsigned result equal to `UINT_MAX + 1 - 5`. In the first initialization you attempt to force that value into a variable of type `int`, which results in overflow with implementation-defined behavior. In your case your implementation behaved so that `var` acquired value `-5`. In other words, the fact that you ended up with `-5` in `var` has no definitive explanation in the domain of abstract C++ language. The result that you observe is just a quirk of your compiler. In some other compiler the first initialization might produce a different value in `var`.

In the second case the type of the expression (which is, again, `unsigned`) becomes the type of the variable, which is initialized with the unsigned value without any overflows.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, because you use `auto`, the compiler will pick `unsigned` in your second example.

Signed and unsigned numbers are stored the same way internally. It is just the way that the number is interpreted when it is printed that makes a difference [and in comparisons, as 'negative' signed numbers are lower than 0, where unsigned numbers can't be less than zero] - signed numbers are checked if they are 'negative', and printed as a minus sign and the negated original number. Unsigned numbers are just treated as whatever the internal representation becomes when printed.

So the values you see are just the two different representations of the same number - signed and unsigned respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In both C and C++, in the vast majority of cases, the type of an expression is determined from the expression itself, without regard to the context in which it appears.

```
int var = 5u - 10;
```

`5u` is of type `unsigned int`; `10` is of type `int`.  The rules for the `-` operator cause the `int` argument to be converted to `unsigned int`, making the expression equivalent to `5u - 10u`.  The result is `UINT_MAX + 1 - 10`, a very large number. The initialization implicitly converts this from `unsigned int` to `signed int`.  Since that value (almost certainly) isn't representable as an `int`, the result of the conversion is implementation-defined. In nearly all existing implementations, the conversion simply reinterprets the unsigned representation as if it were a signed value, resulting in `-5`.  (This applies to systems that use a two's-complement representation for negative values; the resulting simplicity of signed/unsigned conversions is one of the reasons two's-complement is so widely used.)

Note that it would not be possible for `var` to have the value `4294967291`; the largest value that an `int` can hold on your system is (probably) `2147483647`.

```
auto var = 5u - 10;
```

`5u - 10` is evaluated the same way as before, resulting in an `unsigned int` result of `UINT_MAX + 1 - 5`, or `4294967291` on your system.  The `auto` means that `var` takes on the type of the expression, `unsigned int`, so no conversion is performed. (On a system with 16-bit `int`, the result would be `65531`.)

In answer to your question, the constant `10` *is* converted from `int` to `unsigned int` in both cases.